# Problem with importing the module in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm running Flask on Ubuntu with Nginx and uwsgi.

The issue I have is when I try to import the custom module into the Flask it doesn't seem to work.
I'm simply importing the module by:

```
import modulename
```

The modulename is in the same directory as the Flask app.

When looking into uwsgi logs I can see the error:

--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---

This error message is only shown when I'm importing my module, if removed all works fine.

Any suggestions how to fix this or what is causing this message?

Comment: No, it doesn't work either with the dot

Comment: what is the name of the directory try `import directory_name.module_name`

Comment: No, it still doesn't work...

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305654/uwsgi-flask-no-python-application-found-check-your-startup-logs-for-errors)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time I figured out that I had to reload daemon with the command:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

After that I also restarted my project

```
sudo systemctl restart myproject
```

This resolved the issue I had and now I can import my module as expected.