# I'm getting the classic "Permission denied while connecting to upstream" while trying to deploy my flask app on an Nginx server, Ubuntu 21.10 instance

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, flask

I know the question has been asked a million times, and I've tried almost every 'solution' to no avail. I'm thinking that my problem could be unique.

uwsgi.ini:

```
module = wsgi:app
master = true
processes = 5
socket = elekto.sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
logto = /home/richardgrecoson/elekto/elekto.log
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/elekto :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_ip;
location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/richardgrecoson/elekto/elekto.sock;
    }
}
```

/etc/systemd/system/elekto.service

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve myproject
After=network.target

[Service]
User=richardgrecoson
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/richardgrecoson/elekto
Environment="PATH=/home/richardgrecoson/elekto/.venv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/richardgrecoson/elekto/.venv/bin/uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your NGINX is not allowed to r/w/x on the socket file. Lets try some things.

Change the permission of the socket to `0777` and check it with `ls /home/richardgrecoson/elekto/elekto.sock`

In general it is important that the runuser of NGINX is allowed to r/w/x the socket. The runuser of nginx is "normally" `nginx`. Check this by typing `ps -elf |grep nginx`

If it is NGINX I would change the permissions of the socket back to `660` and change the user and group to `nginx`.

With this the nginx user will have access to the socket.

If you want to use a different runuser for the socket as for nginx, create a new user and add it to the nginx group
`usermod -a -G nginx yourusername`. This will work with `660` as well.

Comment: I've tried those suggestions but it's not working. I ran chmod 0777 elekto.sock. I changed it in my `.ini` file to 777. I changed the group and owner to www-data which I got as the runuser of `nginx`

Comment: I changed `user www-data` to `user myusername` in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf. I no longer get the permission issues but I now get 'Internal Server Error' which logs in my logfile as `no python application found, check your startup logs for errors` Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Solved that too. I just had to move my wsgi file around and configure my .init file
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305654/uwsgi-flask-no-python-application-found-check-your-startup-logs-for-errors

Comment: Great! :) I my answer was helpful would appreciate if you could mark is as the answer  :) have good weekend